# getting nodes without texts

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("br").parent().contents().each(function(i) {
   if(this.nodeType == "#Text")
    {
        alert(this.textContent);
    }
});
```

i am trying to select all texts not surrounded by html tags, but separated via `<br>`

doing this, sometimes returns a lot of alert messages, even when there should only be a couple.

i have tried to filter it out using

```
if(this.nodeValue != "") or if(this.textContent != "")
```

but still, empty alert messages pop up.

I suspect its the whitespaces in the html document (i dont control it). I only want to display `this.textContent`, which actually has visible text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text node's node type is 3, so:

```
$('br').parent().contents().each(function() {
    if ( this.nodeType == 3 ) {
      var text = (this.textContent ? this.textContent : this.innerText), temp = text.replace( /\s+/g, '')
        if ( temp.length ) {
            alert( text )
        }
    }
})
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/abalu

Comment: i am getting text is undefined error.

  text = text.replace(/\s+/g, '')

Comment: Try my updated example. My prior one didn't account for br elements.

Comment: If you want to strip the whitespace from alert, you could use .replace( /^\s+|\s+$/, '' ).

Comment: Since you've established you have a text node, you should use `this.nodeValue` or `this.data` (which are equivalent for text nodes) rather than the non-standard `innerText` or `textContent`, which are designed to extract text content from elements.